# How to join these two select statements on related columns Microsoft SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, report

The goal would be to join these data in a table grouped by year_month.

First query:

```
select  tlyear_month,count(user_name) AS agents_lagents_value
 from
    (SELECT distinct 
            USER_NAME
            ,concat(cryear,'-',crmonth) as tlyear_month
        FROM STATUS_REPORT_TABLE_BASIC
        WHERE GROUP_NAME LIKE '%Agent%'
    GROUP BY CRYEAR, CRMONTH,user_name,group_name) sub1
    group by tlyear_month
```

Second query:

```
SELECT 
            concat(cryear,'-',crmonth) tsaff_YEAR_MONTH, 
        CASE -- hardcoded between 2017-01 and 2017-12
            WHEN CRYEAR = 2017  AND CRMONTH = 1 THEN 49
            WHEN CRYEAR = 2017  AND CRMONTH = 2 THEN 47
            WHEN CRYEAR = 2017  AND CRMONTH = 3 THEN 46
            WHEN CRYEAR = 2017  AND CRMONTH = 4 THEN 46
            WHEN CRYEAR = 2017  AND CRMONTH = 5 THEN 47
            WHEN CRYEAR = 2017  AND CRMONTH = 6 THEN 49
            WHEN CRYEAR = 2017  AND CRMONTH = 7 THEN 53
            WHEN CRYEAR = 2017  AND CRMONTH = 8 THEN 54
            WHEN CRYEAR = 2017  AND CRMONTH = 9 THEN 54
            WHEN CRYEAR = 2017 AND CRMONTH = 10 THEN 54
            WHEN CRYEAR = 2017 AND CRMONTH = 11 THEN 51
            WHEN CRYEAR = 2017 AND CRMONTH = 12 THEN 54
            ELSE COUNT(distinctified.USER_NAME)
        END  A_COUNT

    FROM
        (SELECT DISTINCT
            CRYEAR
            ,CRMONTH
            ,USER_NAME
            ,GROUP_NAME
        FROM STATUS_REPORT_TABLE_BASIC
        WHERE GROUP_NAME LIKE '%Agent%' )  AS distinctified
    GROUP BY CRYEAR, CRMONTH
```

First result (not all rows, both of these queries contain data from the same daterange)

```
 2017-1 36
    2017-10 47
    2017-11 50
    2017-12 53
    2017-2  35
    2017-3  36
    2017-4  33
    2017-5  34
    2017-6  34
    2017-7  40
```

Second result (not all rows, both of these queries contain data from the same daterange)

```
2017-1  49
2018-1  55
2017-2  47
2018-2  52
2017-3  46
2018-3  51
2017-4  46
2018-4  49
2017-5  47
2018-5  49
```

I'm kind of new to sql and I've run out of ideas. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please be a bit more specific? How does it know if im referring to query 1 or 2?

Comment: use union all key word between 2 queries and do group by year-month

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. This method does not give the solution I need. I'd like to keep the two seperate columns, I just want to tie them to specific dates.

Comment: show your output instead of saying

Comment: [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use join between two queries

```
     select a.tlyear_month, agents_lagents_value,cnt from 
(select  tlyear_month,count(user_name) AS agents_lagents_value
         from
            (SELECT distinct 
                    USER_NAME
                    ,concat(cryear,'-',crmonth) as tlyear_month
                FROM STATUS_REPORT_TABLE_BASIC
                WHERE GROUP_NAME LIKE '%Agent%'
            GROUP BY CRYEAR, CRMONTH,user_name,group_name) sub1
            group by tlyear_month)a
inner join
(

        SELECT 
                    concat(cryear,'-',crmonth) as t2year_month, 
                CASE -- hardcoded between 2017-01 and 2017-12
                    WHEN CRYEAR = 2017  AND CRMONTH = 1 THEN 49
                    WHEN CRYEAR = 2017  AND CRMONTH = 2 THEN 47
                    WHEN CRYEAR = 2017  AND CRMONTH = 3 THEN 46
                    WHEN CRYEAR = 2017  AND CRMONTH = 4 THEN 46
                    WHEN CRYEAR = 2017  AND CRMONTH = 5 THEN 47
                    WHEN CRYEAR = 2017  AND CRMONTH = 6 THEN 49
                    WHEN CRYEAR = 2017  AND CRMONTH = 7 THEN 53
                    WHEN CRYEAR = 2017  AND CRMONTH = 8 THEN 54
                    WHEN CRYEAR = 2017  AND CRMONTH = 9 THEN 54
                    WHEN CRYEAR = 2017 AND CRMONTH = 10 THEN 54
                    WHEN CRYEAR = 2017 AND CRMONTH = 11 THEN 51
                    WHEN CRYEAR = 2017 AND CRMONTH = 12 THEN 54
                    ELSE COUNT(distinctified.USER_NAME)
                END  as cnt

            FROM
                (SELECT DISTINCT
                    CRYEAR
                    ,CRMONTH
                    ,USER_NAME
                    ,GROUP_NAME
                FROM STATUS_REPORT_TABLE_BASIC
                WHERE GROUP_NAME LIKE '%Agent%' )  AS distinctified
            GROUP BY CRYEAR, CRMONTH)b on a.tlyear_month=b.concat(cryear,'-',crmonth)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. This method does not give the solution I need. I'd like to keep the two seperate columns, I just want to tie them to specific dates.

Comment: could you please show what is your expected output ?

Comment: FIrst column: the dates
Second column: calculated data from query 1
Third column: calculated data from query 2
joined together based on date
So for example:
2017-1 | 36 | 49

Comment: Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 40
No column name was specified for column 1 of 'b'.
Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 40
No column name was specified for column 2 of 'b'.

Comment: column name was missing for query 2, updated it already, you can check now

Comment: Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 40
No column name was specified for column 2 of 'b'.

I have tried replacing the last part of your code with "t2year_month" but same error showed up

Comment: yes, you just copy and paste my current version updated query, another column name was missing that's why it showed up

Comment: Thank you, it is working fine now. Theoretically I could join infinite queries as long as they all have this year_month column in them, right?